# How do the razer key switches compare to cherry mx?

Tags: keyboards

I am a long running user of the cherry mx red key switch, and I love it! I have used both blue and brown and didn't like either of them. I use my keyboard for intense gaming sessions but also for typing, as I am always typing large documents for school. I have a high typing speed of almost 100 WPM so the cherry mx reds don't feel like they are restricting me from typing at my ability, but rather aiding it.

I like the look of the razer blackwidow V2 keyboard but they use their own key switches. I was wondering what razer key switch would most closely compare to the cherry mx red, and any major similarity's and differences, or pros and cons of the razer key switch over the cherry mx red for my purpose (Gaming/Typing 50/50)

Comment: This Wired article might be helpful: https://www.wired.com/2017/03/mechanical-keyboards-round-up/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually using the Razer Blackwidow 2016 Stealth Edition and I really love it , it's really smooth and reactive. Though my girlfriend likes it less than I do because she can't sleep when I play or type things because like a lot of mechanical keyboards it makes some noise, which is a negative.

This is what I found about the Cherry MX Red:
[image: cherry mx red]

This is what I found for the Razer key switches:

[image: razer switch]

So i'd say the yellow Razer switch is the closest thing to what you're searching for.
I think it's a matter of taste more than anything so it would be best for you to go and try them out for yourself before you buy.

Comment: Cherry MX Red is linear, and the only Razor switch that's linear is yellow. Orange is not the closest match.

Comment: I didn't know that , thx for adding it !

Comment: Razer Yellow actuation point is after 1.3mm versus the Cherry Red 2mm, a 35% difference. I don't think you're going to find a much closer comparison but there are significant differences.